# Will this circuit (for a guitar effects pedal) work?

Tags: audio, circuit-design, guitar-pedal

I am a newbie at electronics and am trying to make a fuzz/distortion pedal. This is a schematic I have made[image: Schematic]

My understanding is that the more resistance the more gain so there is a minimum of 100 KΩ resistance, then the 1 MΩ pot controls the gain. Then there is a switch for 'Super Crunch' which is a 5 MΩ resistor. Then there are three clipping options: Symmetrical, Asymmetrical (Single-Sided) and Asymmetrical (Double-Sided). Then there is the volume pot, but I don't know what maximum resistance to use. Then at the end is the bypass switch. Would this work? Or am I being dumb. Thanks.

Comment: You ought to review existing fuzz pedal designs before you design a circuit on your own. This has a number of issues, both electrically and diagrammatically. Potentiometers don't work like that, your input notation is incorrect, and you've got no active circuitry, so no gain.

Comment: I have based this of other circuits. Would you mind pointing out the issues. Thanks.

Comment: Could you link some of the circuits you have based it on? The biggest issue is that you seem to have the idea that resistors and potentiometers amplify the signal. They are passive components.

Comment: Here http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-an-easy-guitar-distortion-pedal-STEP-BY-STEP/step9/null/

Comment: Oh. First off, that's a pretty poor circuit, with absolutely atrocious diagrams. Secondly, notice how there's a transistor in that circuit? The transistor provides some gain. [Here's](http://www.runoffgroove.com/articles.html) a better resource, [here's another one](http://www.muzique.com/schem/projects.htm).

Comment: If I replaced the resistors with an Op-Amp would that that work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34760/discussion-between-uint128-t-and-finnthomas99).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but this isn't going to work, but well done for having a go. Firstly you have misunderstood "gain". You don't get any gain by putting a 1M pot and a 5M resistor in the signal path, that will just attenuate the signal (make it smaller). To get any gain you need something to provide amplification, such as transistors or an IC called an Operational Amplifier (Op-Amp). Once the Op-Amp has amplified the guitar signal to several volts you can then clip it with diodes - you actually have the right idea with the diodes. I suggest you Google "Guitar Fuzz box schematic", schematics for most of the well know fuzz boxes made over the last 30 years are available.

Comment: So if I removed those resistors and had something like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Op-Amp_Inverting_Amplifier.svg/300px-Op-Amp_Inverting_Amplifier.svg.png there it'd work?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by researching Fuzz Face schematics. It is one of the simpler designs, just make sure you build the NPN version. You don't want to start screwing around with negative 9v power supplies just yet. Start with small easy builds and watch videos of the pedals to find out which sounds resonate with you. Then check out websites for pedal building, many will break down the circuit into their most basic functions. Welcome to the rabbit hole.
Breadboarding is a great way to do variations to figure out what each part does.
http://diy.smallbearelec.com/HowTos/BreadboardSiFF/BreadboardSiFF.htm